# Reading array from java servlet in javascript

Tags: javascript, java, arrays, jsp, servlets

Hi like the title says I am trying to read an array from my java Servlet. I am trying to read the array in my java script file.

Java servlet code:
    String graphData[] = dbHandler.select(attributes); // filling the array with data from database.
    request.setAttribute("graphData", graphData);

```
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/displayData.jsp");
dispatcher.forward(request, response);


    <script type="text/javascript">
      var graphData = ['${graphData}'];
      var graphData= pageContext.getAttribute("graphData");
      var graphData = document.getElementById("graphData");
      var GraphData = ['${graphData}'];
      log("test: " + graphData); 
   </script>
```

I tried all those options but none of them worked.
Can someone please tell me what the correct way is to read an array from a java servlet in a jsp page?

Thanks in advance!

edit:

what I can do is print out the data from the array on the JSP page (in the header) with this code:

```
  <c:forEach items="${graphData}" var="temp">
    <c:out value="${temp}"/><br />
  </c:forEach>
```

But I want to use the data from the array in my JS code. which for some reason doesn't work.

Comment: are you trying to read JS data from jsp page?Better to fill in the details in some attribute and submit via form to send to servlet

Comment: @ShivamAggarwal: he clearly mentioned that he reads attribute from servlet in js code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use like this

```
<script>
    var graphData = [
    <c:forEach items="${graphData}" var="graph">
        '<c:out value="${graph}" />',  
    </c:forEach>
    ];
    console.log(graphData);
</script>
```