# How to access spring object list access in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, java, spring, spring-mvc, object

So I use Spring to pass a list of objects into the jsp, but I don't know how to access it's values and properties inside javascript.

So if I use something like:

```
var x = ${objectList};
```

there seems to be an error, when I use chrome to check it.

I would like to do something like this:

```
var x = ${objectList};
for(i=0; i<x.length; i++)
{
document.write(x[i].propertyName);   // property for object i
}
```

I searched for an answer for a few days, but I didn't find one for my problem.

Comment: Can you paste the generated Javascript?

Comment: Is this Java or Javascript?  They are not the same thing - about as similar as Car and Carpet.

Comment: it might help [check my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43388874/reading-array-from-java-servlet-in-javascript/43389655#43389655)

Comment: That actually worked, thank you :) .

Answer (score 0):

Try this to access spring object in javascript

```
<script>
    var data=<c:out value="${objectList}"/>
</script>
```