# how to handle the returned value from spring mvc controller on javascript file

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc

I need your help. I tried all things of my researhes on internet bu I can not do.

I have an jsp file and js file. I included js file to jsp. I want to handle returned values from spring mvc controller on javascript code but I failed.

here is my controller :

```
package com.sample.spring.controller;

import com.sample.hibernate.model.employee.Employee;
import com.sample.hibernate.service.employeeservice.EmployeeService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import java.util.List;


 @Controller
 @RequestMapping("/employee")
 public class EmployeeController {

     @Autowired
     EmployeeService employeeService;

     @RequestMapping(value = {"/","/list"},method = RequestMethod.GET)
     public ModelAndView lisEmployees(){
           List<Employee> employees = employeeService.findAllEmployees();

          return new ModelAndView("allemployees","allEmployees",employees);

      }
 }
```

And here is my allemployees.jsp file :

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ page pageEncoding="UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="<c:url value="/resources/js/sample.js" />"></script>
    <link href="<c:url value="/resources/css/bootstrap.css" />"   rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="<c:url value="/resources/css/bootstrap-theme.css"/>" rel="stylesheet"/>
 </head>
```

```
<c:import url="/resources/templates/allemployees.html" charEncoding="UTF-8" />
```

and here is my sample.js file :

```
var modelList = "${allEmployees}";

var lengthStr = modelList.length;

console.log(lengthStr);
```

I debugged on firebug. I tried ${model},"${model}",${allEmployees},"${allEmployees}" but all this trials I failed.

Could you help me please?

Comment: What do you have if you put your js code directly inside the jsp page?

Comment: @akuma8 I tried 1 min ago and I failed like on the seperatly js file

Comment: Add a Model argument in your method, add explicitly the attribute then return just the view. Somethong like `public ModelAndView lisEmployees(Model model) ..... model.addAttribute("allEmployees",employees);`

Comment: Can you tell what exactly do you want to do with `employees`? Your `employees` list  will be accessible on `allemployees.jsp` page as value of `allEmployees` attribute.

Comment: @akuma8 whats is the difference beetween my code and your code? I tried something like you said but result didn't change.

Comment: @Yogesh Is not clear what is employees on code? employees is a list of employees. I'm trying learn use spring mvc. I want to return some objects and handle with javascript.

Comment: check my answer, it might help [java array in js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43388874/reading-array-from-java-servlet-in-javascript/43389655#43389655)

Comment: @Gurkan Yesilyurt thanks. I'll try but I want to ask you something. When I handle like this "${model}" javascript shows a string this "${model}" I tried all things where I writed on question and I got same things. Does it matter on jstl foreach? I ask because I tried fill a table directly this jstl but I failed. Only I saw in table cells parameters name like this ${employee.name}. Where am I wrong? I'm so sory. Every solutions which I found on web doesn't solve my problem. No examples on web could not properly explain how to access via javascript step by step.

Comment: try var name = '${allEmployees[0].name}'; and check whether work or not. If you want to access a list in js then you have to iterate it on server-side (that's why JSTL, it can easily access the allEmployees object in the request scope). and this article might help [Server side and client side](http://balusc.omnifaces.org/2009/05/javajspjsf-and-javascript.html) written by BalusC.

Comment: @GurkanYesilyurt That things is so simple on Rest Architecture when I worked my old company. I try to learn something new(I have a 4 months to finish my military obligation, I'm an Engiineer Subliuetenant). I'll try your said.

Comment: @GurkanYesilyurt I tried but It doesn't work. I do something wrong but What? I can't see.

Comment: try it in allemployees.jsp with <script> tags. Jsp engine doesn't see in external js(sample.js another request).

Comment: @Gurkan Yesilyurt I tried like you said but doesn't help. I'm trouble with this problem.